# Using method from enum class

Tags: java, enums

I am newbie in JAVA and I am having trouble with enumeration classes. I have a class of type enum named Answers that possesses the method that returns an Answers enumeration constant:

```
import java.util.Random;
enum Answers {
    NO,YES;
    Random rand = new Random();
    Answers ask(){
        int prob = (int) (100*rand.nextDouble());
            
        if(prob > 50)
            return Answers.YES;
        else
            return Answers.NO;
    }
}
```

Nevertheless when trying to print a result using the method I get the error: `variable result not might been initialized` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Answers result;
        switch(result.ask()){
            case NO:
                System.out.println("NO");
                break;
            case YES:
                System.out.println("YES");
                break;   
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps `ask()` should be static? Otherwise `result` needs to be initialized to one of the enum constants before you can invoke a method on the instance.

Comment: Right on, `static` feels like the right solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is telling you that the variable might not be initialized, you are treating the variable result as an instance of Answers, if you want to return an instance of Answers when calling the ask() method, you should probably use a static method like this.

```
    static Answers ask(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int prob = (int) (100*rand.nextDouble());
            
        if(prob > 50)
            return Answers.YES;
        else
            return Answers.NO;
    }
```

And then you can call that method like this.

Answers.ask()

or

Saving it in a variable

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        Answers result = Answers.ask();
        switch(result){
            case NO:
                System.out.println("NO");
                break;
            case YES:
                System.out.println("YES");
                break;   
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the variable result like so :

```
Answers result = Answers.YES
```

Then you can access the methods of the object

So your logic doesn't make sense to put it in the enum, Instead, you can have the enum for yes or no and put the logic to generate random answers in a static method

```
enum Answers {
    NO,YES;
    Random rand = new Random();
    static Answers ask(){
        int prob = (int) (100*rand.nextDouble());
            
        if(prob > 50)
            return Answers.YES;
        else
            return Answers.NO;
    }
}
```

Then use it as following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        switch(Answers.ask()){
            case NO:
                System.out.println("NO");
                break;
            case YES:
                System.out.println("YES");
                break;   
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize result here, so it makes sense that it doesn't compile.
The problem is what is the value of result in your example when you're calling result.ask()?

You probably don't want to assign the result to a variable and could just make ask() a static method.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
static Answer random() { return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? YES : NO ; }
```

## `static`

Be aware that `NO` and `YES` are the instances of your class `Answer`. (By the way, an enum is better named in singular.) So rather than a regular instance method, your `ask` method should be `static`.

Actually, I would not put your `ask` method inside your enum. An enum provides values and data, but should generally not be aware of how it is being used such as randomly selected. But I’ll not dwell on that.

## `ThreadLocalRandom`

Regarding the `Random` class, I recommend using instead [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html). This makes for thread-safe code. You may not need bread-safety, but there is no downside to using `ThreadLocalRandom`. Another benefit to `ThreadLocalRandom` is nat launching a new `Random` object repeatedly. Best of all, `ThreadLocalRandom` has convenient methods such as [`nextBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextBoolean()) without any of the math you were doing.

Call `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` to get the random value generator established for this thread. If not yet established, a generator is started.

Your situation needs only a range of two values to choose between your `NO` and `YES` values. So call `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean()` to generate a `true` or `false` value.

## Ternary statement

Rather than an `if` statement, this situation is a good place for a [ternary statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Computer_science). The compact syntax of a ternary works like this:

```
someTestEvaluatingToTrueOrFalse ? thisValueReturnedIfTrue : thisValueReturnedIfFalse
```

By the way, I changed your method name from `ask` to `random` to better communicate what it actually does.

## Example code

Putting that all together, we have the following code.

```
enum Answer
{
    NO , YES ;

    static Answer random() 
    {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? YES : NO ;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Answer answer = Answer.random() ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DJbefg).